# How to access AppLocalization with key unknown at compile time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I can access localized text with AppLocalization:

```dart
Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.yourAccountIsBlocked)
```

Is there any way to access the localized text using key unknown at compile time?

Smth like this:

```dart
String key = "yourAccountIsBlocked";
...
Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)![key])
```

Comment: Short answer is NO. If you actually take a look at the file created by AppLocalizations, you will realize why it will not work